# Shopify Dropdown Menu hidden behind banner

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

I am currently building a Shopify store and have some dropdown menus but for some reason these are being hidden behind a banner that I have added underneath. I have built the store using the Timber Framework and I have attached an image of the dropdown menu being hidden.

How can I can fix this?

[image: site]

Comment: Perhaps you can try to use `z-index`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index Note you'd need to have `position` defined on the element different than static

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried adding the z-index but no difference.

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue the other day, can't comment yet but could you post your site link? If not check your #PageContainer styling and make sure overflow: hidden; isn't there.

Comment: Alex, can post my link but locked with a password so not sure how to share that with you.

Comment: Also checked but its only the homepage that has this issue so has to be something to do with the banner as its the only page I have it on

Comment: Hi Alex, the pagecontainer styling is there with overflow:hidden but removing makes no difference..